# jquery - datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying out the jquery datepicker but can't get it to work. I know I must be missing something simple. Here is my code:

HTML :

```
<div class="demo">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
    <p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.  Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a sma    ll overlay.  Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as t    he input's value.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

JS :

```
 $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
```

This renders a text field, but no jquery calendar. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date picker is in jQuery UI libs.. You need to include that for date picker to work.

Edit: You need to include this,

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Add this in your html,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked. The only issue remaining is that it the calendar now comes up with a clear background which overlaps the field below it making the calendar unreadable. Is there a way to specify the background color of this?

Comment: Try adding their CSS, you should try jQuery theme picker which has some cool themes. Download one you like and include them in your html. link here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ -> On the left pane, go to galary, select one and download

Answer (score 1):

You haven't loaded the datepicker jquery file, just the main jquery file. Check the example given [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/default.html)

Answer (score 1):

Include the datapicker Javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
```

[jquery.datePicker.js](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js)